# NodeJS: Keeping library files DRY

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, dry

I've recently started working on a non-trivial project in CoffeeScript and I'm struggling with how best to deal with registering exports etc.  I'm writing it in a very 'pythonesque' manner, with individual files effectively being 'modules' of related classes and functions.  What I'm looking for is the best way to define classes and functions locally AND in `exports`/`window` with as little repetition as possible.

At the moment, I'm using the following in every file, to save writing `exports.X = X` for everything in the file:

```
class module
  # All classes/functions to be included in exports should be defined with `@`
  # E.g.
  class @DatClass

exports[name] = item for own name, item of module
```

I've also looked at the possibility of using a function (say, `publish`) that puts the passed class in `exports`/`window` depending on its name:

```
publish = (f) ->
  throw new Error 'publish only works with named functions' unless f.name?
  ((exports ? window).namespace ?= {})[f.name] = f

publish class A
# A is now available in the local scope and in `exports.namespace`
# or `window.namespace`
```

This, however, does not work with functions as, as far as I know, they cannot be 'named' in CoffeeScript (e.g. `f.name` is always `''`) and so `publish` cannot determine the correct name.

Is there any method that works like `publish` but works with functions?  Or any alternative ways of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an ugly hack but you can use the following :

```
class module.exports
  class @foo
    @bar = 3
```

And then :

```
require(...).foo.bar // 3
```

Comment: Hacky, sure, but admittedly neat. Works /w functions too, if you declare like @fn = (args...) -> 'results of fn()'. I for one will be severely tempted to use this..

Comment: This is very neat.  What makes it hacky?

Comment: In my opinion it's only mildly hacky, since it's not a technique that's mentioned in any official documentation. That could just as well have to do with it falling btw the chairs of Node & CoffeeScript, though.

Comment: The hacky portion is that here, you assign a function (actually a constructor) to `module.exports` and add attributes to that function in the form of simili-static methods, instead of assigning an object to `module.exports`. Moreover, if you need to use `bar` somewhere in this module, you'd need to use the full path `exports.foo.bar`, which is a pain.

Comment: This can actually be shortened generally due to the boilerplate Coffeescript attaches to the compiled javascript: `(function() { ... }).call(this);` - it means the scope of the script is already `module.exports` so you can drop the outer `class module.exports` definition and go straight to `class @foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The old

```
(function (exports) {
  // my code

  exports.someLib = ...
})(typeof exports === "undefined" ? window : exports);
```

Is a neat trick that should do what you want.

If writing that wrapper boilerplate is a pain then automate it with a build script.

Comment: I believe CoffeeScript already does exactly that when it compiles the script.  My issue with this is that defining classes properly leads to repetition: `exports.SomeClass = class SomeClass`, without the second `SomeClass` the resulting function won't have a `name` attribute, which prohibits useful reflection.

Comment: @connec so what? seriously. just do `class SomeClass` and then do `exports.SomeClass = SomeClass` at the end. I dont call this repetition, I call this having well defined exports.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm hoping a more concise solution exists.  Your method is fine if you only have a few classes but for a module with dozens of classes (exceptions, tokens, nodes, etc.) this would be very tedious and error prone.

Comment: @connec why are you exporting dozens of classes. The problem is not that it's tedious, the problem is that your API is bloated.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm looking for is the best way to define classes and functions locally AND in `exports`/`window` with as little repetition as possible.

It's impossible to do something like

```
exports.x = var x = ...;
```

without writing `x` twice in JavaScript (without resorting to black magicks, i.e. `eval`), and the same goes for CoffeeScript. Bummer, I know, but that's how it is.

My advice would be to not get too hung up on it; that kind of repetition is common. But do ask yourself: "Do I really need to export this function or variable *and* make it locally available?" Cleanly decoupled code doesn't usually work that way.

Answer (score 0):

There's an exception to the "no named functions" rule: classes. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/PxBgn/

```
exported = (clas) ->
  console.log clas.name
  window[clas.name] = clas
...
exported class Snake extends Animal
  move: ->
    alert "Slithering..."
    super 5
```